# Can this code be shorter

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Map<String, List<String>> hash = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (String s: dict){
        hash.compute(s.substring(2)),
            (k, v)-> {  if (v == null){
                return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s));
            }
            else{
                v.add(s);
            }
            return v;
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to make the compute part cleaner? The add method doesn't return a List, it makes the code very long.

Comment: Shall we take a guess what language this is…? Also: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it?

if **dist** a collection

```
Map<String, List<String>> hash = dict.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.substring(2)));
```

or if **dist** a array

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = Stream.of(dist).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.substring(2)));
```

Comment: This way is really very clean and neat.Thanks

Comment: Sure, it is @Roma

Comment: when i vote your answer, it says, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Roma's answer is likely the most idiomatic Java language now that streams are here.

If you wanted to keep a similar structure to what you currently have you could use:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> hash = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s: dict) {
        hash.computeIfAbsent(s.substring(2), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is really helpful